# Höfliche Bestätigung für "danke sehr"

Tags: idiom, politeness

Ich habe jemandem etwas erledigt. Sie hat sich bei mir bedankt.

Nun möchte ich etwas ähnliches wie "sehr gerne" antworten, zum Beispiel:

- "sehr gerne" (zu kurz)
- "es freut mich auch von meiner Seite" (Spiegelübersetzung von einer anderen Sprache, auf deutsch klingt es wahrscheinlich mindestens ungewöhnlich)

Was könnte ich sagen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Gern geschehen.
- Bitte schön.
- Keine Ursache.
- Es war mir ein Vergnügen.
- Jederzeit wieder.

sind häufige Floskeln für diesen Zweck. Die Länge der Floskel sagt nichts über die Ernsthaftigkeit, sondern der Ton macht die Musik.

Eine Formulierung, die man jetzt häufiger hört, von der ich nicht weiß wo sie herkommt, und die wohl lustig sein soll, wäre noch "Nicht dafür!". Da ich sie selbst nicht mag und annehme, dass sie auch bei anderen eher Befremden hervorruft (wofür denn sonst?) empfehle ich sie nicht.

Comment: Der scherzhafte Ausdruck „nicht dafür“ kommt in Norddeutschland häufig vor, allerdings bevorzugt in der hier umgangssprachlichen getrennten Form „da nich(t) für“.

Comment: *`Es war mir ein Vergnügen`* halte ich für übertrieben, da fühlt sich der/die Angesprochene auf den Arm genommen. (in der verkürzten Form - *war mir ein Vergnügen* - könnte es vielleicht durchgehen) ...und *`Bitte schön`* trifft es nicht so ganz, finde ich. nun ja, sicherlich Geschmachssache.

Comment: @Wolf: Du verkehrst vielleicht in den falschen Kreisen. :)

Comment: @userunknown *`Du verkehrst vielleicht in den falschen Kreisen.`* -- eher nicht. Ich versuche lediglich zu vermeiden, einen Nicht-Muttersprachler durch einen zu gut gemeinten Rat zum Ziel des Spotts zu machen. Die Frage ist doch, wer wann wem gegenüber welche Wendung gebraucht. Und in dieser Hinsicht sind *gern geschehen* und *keine Ursache* am unverfänglichsten.

Comment: @Wolf: PeterH fand "sehr gerne" zu kurz, also schlage ich ihm auch was längeres vor. Richtig betont macht er sich damit nicht lächerlich. Falsch betont macht er sich mit allem vielleicht lächerlich. Ohne weiteren Kontext kann man schwer beurteilen, in welchen Kreisen die Formulierung gebraucht werden soll. Ein Hinweis, den wir haben, ist, dass ihm "gern geschehen" zu kurz erscheint. Jetzt Du.

Answer (score 9):

Kurze Höflichkeitsformeln als Antwort auf eine Dankesäußerung („Vielen Dank!“, „Ich danke Ihnen für Ihre Hilfe!“) sind beispielsweise

> Bitte!
>
> Bitte sehr!
>
> Bitte schön!
>
> Gern geschehen!
>
> Sehr gern!
>
> Gerne!
>
> Selbstverständlich!

Längere Höflichkeitsformeln, die vermutlich eher der in Frage gesuchten Form entsprechen, jedoch nicht in jedem Fall passen, beinhalten oft das Wort *Vergnügen:*

> Es ist/war mir ein Vergnügen (d. h., „ich tue es sehr gern“/„ich habe es sehr gern getan“).
>
> Das Vergnügen ist ganz meinerseits.
>
> Das Vergnügen ist ganz auf meiner Seite.
>
> Mit Vergnügen!
>
> Mit dem größten Vergnügen!

Man kann einer Dankesäußerung unter Umständen auch höflich widersprechen:

> „Vielen Dank!“
> – „*Ich* habe zu danken!“

Comment: Man könnte noch "kein Problem" als kurze Floskel ergänzen, wenn man z.B. betonen will, dass es keine Umstände bereitet hat zu helfen.

Answer (score 8):

Eine mögliche Antwort wäre "Gern geschehen", vergleichbar mit dem englischen "You're welcome."
Das ist zwar nicht wirklich länger, aber ist meiner Meinung nach die gängige Antwort.

Comment: finde ich auch, gleichauf mit *keine Ursache*